# почему java не считывает последую строку?

Tags: java, строки, scanner

возникает проблема со Scanner - сначала ввожу кол-во строк, затем считываю их в массив,попутно убирая мусор, но почему-то последняя строка не считывается

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = in.nextInt();
    String[] nomers = new String[N];
    System.out.println(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        String nomer = in.nextLine();
        String newNomer = nomer.replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]+", "");
        nomers[i] = newNomer.replace("+","");
    }
    for (String l:nomers
         ) {
        System.out.println(l);

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю реализовать код так (не самое красивое решение, потому что не знаю класс Scanner):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine());
    String[] nomers = new String[n];
    System.out.println(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String nomer = in.nextLine();
        String newNomer = nomer.replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]+", "");
        nomers[i] = newNomer.replace("+", "");
    }
    for (String l : nomers) {
        System.out.println(l);
    }

}
```

}

Описание `nextInt` не говорит, что он читает всю строку. Следовательно, остаток строки, даже если он пустой, сразу же попадает сразу в первое чтение строки в цикле (`nextLine`). В этом можно убедиться, если в начальной версии кода на первый запрос (о размере) ввести, например `3 a`, а потом на два запроса `b` и `c`, то `а` станет самым первым элементом массива.